# How to copy a char pointer into a char array?

Tags: c, string, pointers, arrays

So I have a pointer to a char array:

```
temporaryVariable->arrayOfElements; // arrayOfElements is char*
```

I would like to copy into my char array declared with square brackets:

```
char stringArray[MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(stringArray, temporaryVariable->arrayOfElements, sizeof(stringArray));
stringArray[sizeof(stringArray) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: I'd also note he could check before hand to see if it would fit if truncating the string is not suitable

Answer (score 1):

#### this code is also ok.

```
snprintf(stringArray,MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH + 1,"%s",temporaryVariable->arrayOfElements);
```